# Online Encyclopedia of Error-Correcting Codes

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, coding-theory

Is there some kind person on the internet who is making an exhaustive collection of error-correcting codes? I'm looking for something analogous to the OEIS. I want to ask questions like "what is this code called?", "what codes exist with a given block size and rate?" and "are any good decoding algorithms known for this code?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Code Tables](http://codetables.de/) allows you to look up codes by their underlying field, length, and dimension. It doesn't have an option to search by rate, but you can view the full table for a field and mentally draw a diagonal line down the table to find codes with rate near what you're looking for.